# How do I poping up the Save or Open File VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, browser

My goal is to attempt that popping up the option to save or open the file that already been created.

Here's my code :

```
 Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "PERIOD"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 2) = "PARTS_NO_FG"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 3) = "QTY_ASSY"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 4) = "COSTING1"

        xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 1) = "201212"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 2) = "01125E6041"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 3) = "5"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 4) = "0"


        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("D:\TemplateAssy.xlsx")

        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
```

Then how to popping up when I execute this program VB.NET thanks

Comment: use the FileDialog class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653556.aspx

Comment: use this search string in your search engine: "open file dialog excel vb.net"

Answer (score 2):

Just turn on the Alerts. It should solve the problem

```
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 workbook.SaveAs(filePath)

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Source: http://p2p.wrox.com/vb-how/63900-disabling-second-excel-save-prompt.html

revesed answer from shasur

EDIT : IN your case

```
 xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True

 xlWorkbook.SaveAs(filePath)

 xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Also try 
   xlApp.Visible = True

may be able to give you pointers on where / why its not showing up.